# In an orcacle database what do the rows in user_contraints depict?

Tags: oracle

I have run the following query in my oracle database but the results are not clear to me.

```
SELECT constraint_name,
       constraint_type,
       search_condition,
       r_constraint_name,
       delete_rule,
       status
FROM   user_constraints
```

What is the meaning of each column?

Comment: [Please see this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From ORACLE [**docs**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022)

***USER_CONSTRAINTS***

> USER_CONSTRAINTS describes all constraint definitions on tables owned
>   by the current user.

***Columns***

- **constraint_name** - Name of the constraint definition
- **constraint_type** - Type of constraint definition:

  C (check constraint on a table)

  P (primary key)

  U (unique key)

  R (referential integrity)

  V (with check option, on a view)

  O (with read only, on a view)
- **search_condition** - Text of search condition for a check constraint
- **r_constraint_name** - Name of the unique constraint definition for
  referenced table
- **delete_rule** - Delete rule for a referential constraint (CASCADE or NO
  ACTION)
- **status** - Enforcement status of constraint (ENABLED or DISABLED)

Comment: A. CREATE TABLE ord_details 
    (ord_no NUMBER(2) UNIQUE, NOT NULL, 
    item_no NUMBER(3), 
    ord_date date DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL); 
B. CREATE TABLE ord_details 
    (ord_no NUMBER(2) , 
    item_no NUMBER(3), 
    ord_date date DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT ord_uq UNIQUE (ord_no), 
    CONSTRAINT ord_pk PRIMARY KEY (ord_no)); 
please can you tell why this two methods are invalid?